# How to make flutter_blue to scan bluetooth devices other than Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices like mobile phones or PCs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

The problem is that I am trying to scan for other mobile devices near me using flutter_blue but it is made only for devices like earbuds or speaker. So it is not able to show me other devices in the scan results.
Is there any solution for this?
Is there any other package available for doing this?

Comment: This is impossible to do on iOS due to OS restrictions. Are you trying to do this exclusively on Android? For Android, you'll need something that calls [`startDiscovery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()). (Package recommendations are generally off-topic for Stack Overflow; but you'd want to look for something that uses BluetoothAdapter.)

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that on Android phones.

Comment: In that case, BluetoothAdapter is bridged to Flutter: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_android/latest/android_bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter-class.html, but there are other packages like https://github.com/GeekyAnts/flutter-bluetooth-adapter

Comment: Is it necessary that other devices should have my app installed?

Comment: Actually I just want their Bluetooth addresses for some reason. I just want the list of Bluetooth adress of the phones near me.

Comment: I'm not quite certain if your question is what you think it is. You said you wanted "other than Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices." Mobile phones are BLE devices. PCs sometimes are. Earbuds and speakers sometimes are, and sometimes aren't. But mobile phones and PCs may not advertise anything (BLE or otherwise). A device that doesn't broadcast any information cannot be discovered. It would be helpful if you explained what your "some reason" is.

Comment: Actually I am trying to just fetch the list of Bluetooth adress of the bluetooth present in the mobile phones near me. And for that I am trying to use the example given in flutter_blue documentation but is only scanning my Bluetooth earbuds and earphones and no other devices like my friends phone or my PC.

Comment: Is your friend's phone and your PC advertising anything? (It is common that they wouldn't.) In general, there is no way to get a list of every mobile phone near you within an app. Is there some other tool you're using that does discover these devices? Perhaps we can explore what protocol that tool is using.

Comment: Do keep in mind that even if you got the addresses, most devices randomly change their addresses often, so it's not quite clear what you'd do with this information. A quick introduction to the many kinds of addresses Bluetooth devices advertise: https://novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Have tried everything but it has no solution.

You **can not connect** with other PCs and devices via Bluetooth connection, android does not give permissions for this because of security reasons, you can **only connect with BLE devices** with any Flutter Bluetooth library.

You can check Android Documentation For more.

Comment: Actually I just want to scan them. And I want their Bluetooth addresses for some reason. I just want the list of Bluetooth adress of the phones.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Is there some other ways of scanning nearby devices other than Bluetooth or Wifi-Hotspot?